# "PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here" error when inserting a date from function

Tags: sql, oracle, date, plsql, insert

I have the following SQL script to fill a 'Billings' table with random data using PL/SQL:

```
DECLARE
    dgStartDate     DATE;
    dgEndDate       DATE;
    dgRandomDate    DATE;

FUNCTION getRandomDate(pStartDate IN DATE, pEndDate IN DATE) RETURN DATE
    IS
        dRandomDate     DATE;
        piStartNumber   PLS_INTEGER;
        piEndNumber     PLS_INTEGER;
    BEGIN
        piStartNumber := TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(pStartDate, 'J'));
        piEndNumber := TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(pEndDate, 'J'));

        dRandomDate := TO_DATE(TRUNC(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(piStartNumber, piEndNumber)), 'J');

        RETURN dRandomDate;
    END;

BEGIN
    dgStartDate := TO_DATE('01/01/2012', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
    dgEndDate := TO_DATE('31/12/2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY');

    dgRandomDate := getRandomDate(dgStartDate, dgEndDate);
FOR loop_counter IN 1..28 LOOP
INSERT INTO billings(id_billing, id_account, total_billing, due_billing)
VALUES (loop_counter, '123456', round(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0,2000),2), TO_CHAR(dRandomDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY'));
END LOOP;
COMMIT;
END;
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
ORA-06550: line 45, column 76:
PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here
ORA-06550: line 44, column 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

The error is in the date part inside the INSERT statement, but the date function is returning the correct value. I don't know how to make it work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like we have different line numbers, which line is 44?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your error is being caused by accidentally using the wrong variable name in your `INSERT` statement:  If you look closely, you will notice that you declared a variable called `dgRandomDate`:

```
dgRandomDate := getRandomDate(dgStartDate, dgEndDate);
```

However, here is what you pass in your `INSERT` statement:

```
TO_CHAR(dRandomDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

You probably intended to do this:

```
TO_CHAR(dgRandomDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

**Update:**

I don't see anything wrong with calling your user-defined function from inside the `INSERT` statement, so try doing this:

```
BEGIN

FOR loop_counter IN 1..28 LOOP
INSERT INTO billings(id_billing, id_account, total_billing, due_billing)
VALUES (loop_counter, '123456', round(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0,2000),2),
        TO_CHAR(getRandomDate(TO_DATE('01/01/2012', 'DD/MM/YYYY'),
                              TO_DATE('31/12/2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY')), 'DD/MM/YYYY'));
END LOOP;
COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: If I do that, the random date function wouldn't work in the loop. It inserts the same date in every 28 rows. Tried to move it inside the loop but I got: ORA-01843: not a valid month

Comment: @DavidAdders I understand what you are trying to do now; you want a new random date for each iteration of the loop.  Why don't you try just calling your custom function directly from the `INSERT` statement?

Comment: Thanks for the update, just tried that but got the following: PLS-00231: function 'GETRANDOMDATE' may not be used in SQL; PL/SQL: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier. Weird

Comment: You need to define your function `getRandomDate()` as standalone.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32505663/pls-00231-function-may-not-be-used-in-sql) for more information.  After you do this, the error should go away.